# Evaluating the limit of a somewhat Gaussian integral

Tags: real-analysis

Any clues on how to evaluate
$$\underset{n-> \infty}{\text{lim}} \int_{1}^{\infty} n e^{-x^{\delta}}(1 - e^{-x^{\delta}})^n dx $$
where $0< \delta <1$.  I was thinking of using the Generalized Lebesgue Dominated convergence theorem, but unsure on how to proceed.  Another option under potential consideration is Laplace's Method: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method. Thank you to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 1):

We may consider that
$$ f_n(x) = (n+1)e^{-x}(1-e^{-x})^n $$
is a probability density function over $\mathbb{R}^+$, with an absolute maximum located at $x=\log(n+1)$, 
in which the value of the function is $\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^n\to\frac{1}{e}$. Additionally,
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty} x\cdot f_n(x)\,dx = H_{n+1}. $$

Our integral can be written as
$$ \frac{n}{n+1}\int_{1}^{+\infty} x^{1/\delta-1}\cdot f_n(x)\,dx $$
hence it is expected to diverge like $\log(n)^{1/\delta-1}$ for large values of $n$.